# How to load local widget file in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, widget

I have a widget called employee-widget and this **employee-widget.js** file located in my Angular application folder(just added for src reference). I am calling employee-widget.js as below, but widget is not loading.

**Option 1:**

```
<div>
    <h4>Calling employee widget</h4>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/src/assets/employee-app.0.1.0.js"></script>

       <employee-widget></employee-widget>
</div>
```

Note: no errors in console log and just displaying "Calling employee widget"

**Option 2:**

**EmployeeContainer.ts**

```
export class EmployeeContainerComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
    console.log("Registration");
     this.addWidget("/src/assets/employee-app.0.1.0.js");
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  addWidget(url: string) {
    console.log("running registraion page");
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    const widget = document.createElement("employee-widget");

    // The widgets element is a simple <div> with id="widgets"
    const widgets = document.getElementById("widgets");
    if (!widgets) {
      return;
    }
    widgets.appendChild(widget);
  }
}
```

**employeecontainer.html**

```
<div>
        <h4>Calling employee widget</h4>
</div>
```

> Error at line document.body.appendChild(script);

*

> component.ts:21 GET
>   http://localhost:4400//src/assets/employee-app.0.1.0.js
>   net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

*

Please suggest what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: hi ,did you still have the same problem ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the assets folder will be available after building the project in the same place of the project files so you just need to remove the **src** from the path

```js
export class EmployeeContainerComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
    console.log("Registration");
     this.addWidget("assets/employee-app.0.1.0.js");
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  addWidget(url: string) {
    console.log("running registraion page");
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    const widget = document.createElement("employee-widget");

    // The widgets element is a simple <div> with id="widgets"
    const widgets = document.getElementById("widgets");
    if (!widgets) {
      return;
    }
    widgets.appendChild(widget);
  }
}
```

> the first option will not work because you can't include the script tag in the body of the component template so you need to use the second option by create the tag dynamically

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z34chu)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your `EmployeeContainer.ts`

```
import "../../assets/employee-app.0.1.0.js";
```

Nothing else you're doing seems necessary without you explaining what a *widget* is or why you're trying to use it inside an Angular framework.